# VIM re-mapping [[ & ]] not giving the same result

Tags: vim

I'm trying to remap the section movements keys in VIM [[ & ]] to replace the cursor in the middle of the screen after the command.

```
nnoremap ]] ]] <bar> :normal! zz<cr>
nnoremap [[ [[ <bar> :normal! zz<cr>
```

The first one is working as expected but the second one doesn't. It works only one time if the cursor is not already at the closest bracket {. It doesn't move to the previous one.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you simply try this two mappings?

```
nnoremap ]] ]]zz
nnoremap [[ [[zz
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. That's the first thing I tried but I somehow got and error: zz is not an editor command.

Comment: It should be noted some languages alter the default mappings of `[[` and `]]` to make them more effective for that specific filetype. e.g. python, ruby, php, sql, vim, etc.